# Add ring around selected tab in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottom-nav-view

Is there a way to put a ring around a selected tab using `BottomNavigationView` the way Instagram does when you click on the profile tab?

In this case, the profile tab has a gray ring around the photo.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd set the `app:itemBackground` with a checked state selector with centered oval shape

Selector: `drawable/rounded_selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <size android:width="35dp" android:height="35dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And set that to the `BottomNavigationView`:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/rounded_selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" />
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

> How would you do it if you wanted only one of the tabs to show the circle selector? The way Instagram does it only for the profile.

You'd set that to the menu item by combining drawable layers into LayerDrawable, then set that back to the menu item:

drawable/circle_border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:width="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <size
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp" />
</shape>
```

And in code:

```
val item = bottomNavView.menu.findItem(R.id.profile_item) // change to the id of the profile item

val border = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
    resources,
    R.drawable.circle_border, null
) as GradientDrawable
val layerDrawable = LayerDrawable(arrayOf(item.icon, border))
item.icon = layerDrawable
```

Comment: How would you do it if you wanted only one of the tabs to show the circle selector? The way instagram does it only for the profile.

Comment: Just got it. Sorry I didn't use Instagram before. Let me think of it, probably they don't use BNV

Comment: I like your solution though. It's just I need the circle for only one of the tabs.

Comment: @Micro Just updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: I had to detect when a tab was pressed and run the code to add circle_border but it worked. Thank you.